# Python get random value when using min() when there is more than one match

Tags: python-3.x, random, min

I have the following code:

```
dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 5, 'd':1, 'e': 5, 'f': 1}
get_min = min(dict, key=dict.get)
```

As you can see here there is actually three `min()` matches "a", "d" and "f" with the value of `1`.

This will return "a" 100% of the time as that is what `min()` is designed to do from what I am reading. However, I have a need where I would like to randomly get back "a", "d" or "f" instead of just "a".

Is there a way I can do this using `min()` or some other way (maybe lambda, I am not very good at it)? I thought this would be pretty simple but it turns out it is not :P. I can get this working with some for loops and creating lists but I was looking for the shortest way possible.

Your thoughts would be appreciated!

Thanks,

jAC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
import random
dic = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 5, 'd':1, 'e': 5, 'f': 1}

a = random.choice([k for k,v in dic.items() if v == min(dic.values())])
```

Comment: This was exactly what i needed! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`np.random.choice([k for k in dict.keys() if dict[key]==min(dict.values())])`

Comment: The community [encourages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712) adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers. As explained [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837): "While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value." - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/28387300)